# Multiples of $n$ in the format $[4]^+[0]^*$

Tags: prime-numbers, puzzle

For a given number $n$ I want to find the lowest integer multiple of $n$ that is represented in decimal as the following regular expression: $[4]^+[0]^*$

Examples of numbers that are generated by that regex are: `4`, `40`, `44`, `400`, `440`,  `444`

Notice that `404` is not a member.

So far what I figured out experimentally is that for a given number $n$ composed of two prime factors $p_1$ and $p_2$ the number of $4$s is  $(p_1-1)(p_2-1)/2$.

Does anyone know an exact formula for figuring out the number of $4$s and $0$s in the minimum multiple described above?

Comment: what does [4]*[0] mean

Comment: it's a regex to describe the number in decimal format

Comment: @SakethMalyala it means zero  or more `4` followed by one or more `0`

Comment: @ppaulojr  4,  44, 444 do not satisfy this regualr expression. Ther must be at least one trailing 0. but, 0, 00, 000 satisfy the expression.

Comment: @ppaulojr a simpler notation is `4*0+` there are no brackets needed.

Comment: I edited the regex to match (I added brackets just to no confuse it with a math formula)

Comment: I don' t understand the question. How is n related to the lowest integer that satisfies the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, factor $n$ into $2^a5^bc$  The number of zeros will be $\max(a-2,b)$ where the $-2$ comes from the $4$s in your number.  The number of $4$s will be the length of the repeat in the decimal of $\frac 1c$, which is the minimum $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod c$ except that if you have a factor of $3$ you multiply by  $3$ and if you have a factor $9$ you multiply by $9$.

Comment: It seems correct, but how did you figure this out?

Comment: Basically you need $c$ to divide into a repunit, a number of the form $1111$, so you can multiply it by $4$ to get the number you are looking for.  The special rules for $3$ and $9$ come about because $3$ divides $10-1=9$, but you need to be thinking of $3$ dividing $111$ which you can multiply up to $444$.

Comment: But how did you figure this out so quickly? What previous knowledge did you use here @RossMillikan

Comment: I wonder that too. Which theorems did you use to reach this formula. The repunit part is puzzling me. #kudos for the answer

Comment: Consider for example $1/41 = 0.0243902439...$  This number is also equal to $\frac{2439}{99999}$, which means that $99999 = 9\cdot11111$ is a multiple of 41 (and since 41 is not a multiple of 3, 11111 is a multiple of 41).  Indeed, 11111 is the smallest such "repunit" that is a multiple of 41, or else 1/41 would repeat with a smaller period. (e.g. 1/41 is also equal to $\frac{243902439}{9999999999}$... but 10 isn't the smallest repeating chunk.) So @RossMillikan counting the length of the repeating unit of $1/c$ gives you the smallest number of the form $111...11$ that is a multiple of $c$.

Comment: It comes from decimal expansions of $\frac 1c$.  Every number $c$ will have a repeating decimal with some number $k$ of digits.  When you do the long division of $c$ into $1$, the remainders will cycle.  That cycle cannot be longer than $c-1$ as there are only that many possible remainders besides $0$.  Then $c$ divides $10^k-1$, which is a number with $k\ 9$s.  As long as $c$ doesn't have a factor $3$ it will also divide $\frac 19(10^k-1)$, which is a $k$ digit repunit.  It then divides $\frac 49(10^k-1)$ which is a string of $4$s like you require.